# Switch_to_blog() outside wordpress

Tags: multisite, switch-to-blog

how can I load switch_to_blog() function outside wordpress?

```
$blog_id = '7';
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
switch_to_blog($blog_id);
echo get_option('blogname');
restore_current_blog();
echo 'You switched back.';
```

I get error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function set_prefix() on a non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 126

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**
It can be loaded but without any function just this code ? What global variables is missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible.

From the Codex page [Integrating WordPress with your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website), which explains how to use WordPress "outside" of WordPress:

> These directions will not work on a MultiSite Network.

Comment: Yes I have tried but I guess where is some method.